# node iterate a list of strings in lazy

Tags: node.js, list, foreach, coffeescript

```
lazy = Lazy()
        .lines
        .map(String)

    lazy.forEach (line) ->
        console.log line

lazy.emit('data', listoflines)
```

The thing is, I have a header line,
which I need to handle separately

if I do

```
num = 0
lazy.forEach (line) ->
   console.log num
   if num == 0
      console.log "header"
      #header
   else
      console.log line #rest
   num = num + 1
```

it doesn't work, I only get to num = 0!
Not sure how this is handled internally...

I can't use skip because I need the first line as header with its information.

Comment: and which language is this? because it's not Node.js flavoured JavaScript.

Comment: well spotted. coffeescript

Comment: The output of this is "0" and "header"...nothing more :(

Answer (score 0):

My construct was a bit wrong, but anyway, I decided to just skip the first line.

```
lazy = Lazy()
    lazy.lines.map(String).skip(1).forEach (line) ->
      #do the work
```